# GetMarkedReachedSignal isn't a valid member of AnimationTrack?

Tags: scripting, roblox

So I’m trying to make two functions happen upon a marker being reached in an animation, however it says:
“GetMarkedReachedSignal is not a valid member of AnimationTrack” I’m really confused.

Heres my code:

`

```
script.Parent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    print("Started")
    local on = true
    local char = plr.Character
    local fist = game.Lighting.DivergentFists:Clone()
    local leftfist = game.Lighting.DivergentFists2:Clone()
    local anim =  script.Parent.Parent.DiverGentAnim
    local weld = Instance.new("ManualWeld")
    local leftweld = Instance.new("ManualWeld")


    local function RightHandEmit()
    fist.Parent = char.RightHand
    fist.CFrame = char.RightHand.CFrame

    weld.Parent = char.RightHand
    weld.Part0 = char.RightHand
    weld.Part1 = fist
    weld.C0 = CFrame.new(0,-1,0)
    
    local function FlameEmit()
        while on == true do
            fist.Attachment.BlackFlames:Emit(10)
            fist.Attachment.Flames:Emit(10)
            wait(.1)
        end
    end
    
    local function SparksEmit()
        while on == true do
            fist.Attachment.Aura:Emit(10)
            fist.Attachment.Main:Emit(10)
            wait(.1)
        end
    end
    
    spawn(SparksEmit)
        spawn(FlameEmit)
    end
    
    local function LeftHandEmit()
        leftfist.Parent = char.LeftHand
        leftfist.CFrame = char.LeftHand.CFrame

        leftweld.Parent = char.LeftHand
        leftweld.Part0 = char.LeftHand
        leftweld.Part1 = leftfist
        leftweld.C0 = CFrame.new(0,-1,0)

        local function LeftFlameEmit()
            while on == true do
                leftfist.Attachment.BlackFlames:Emit(10)
                leftfist.Attachment.Flames:Emit(10)
                wait(.1)
            end
        end

        local function LeftSparksEmit()
            while on == true do
                leftfist.Attachment.Aura:Emit(10)
                leftfist.Attachment.Main:Emit(10)
                wait(.1)
            end
        end
        spawn(LeftFlameEmit)
        spawn(LeftSparksEmit)
    end
    
    local load = char.Humanoid.Animator:LoadAnimation(anim)
    
    load:Play()
    
    load:GetMarkerReachedSignal("ReachedStart"):Connect(function()
        print("Reached")
        spawn(LeftHandEmit)
        spawn(RightHandEmit)
    end)

    
end)
```

`

Any help is appreciated, thanks! (This is all on the server by the way)

I tried doing it on the client but nothing happened

Comment: Heyo, the error indicates that you've got a typo when typing `GetMarkerReachedSignal`, but the code you've shared doesn't have this typo. Is there anywhere else in your code where you've made the typo `GetMarkedReachedSignal`?

Comment: I don't think so, that was the end of the code, this was all on the server from an event but the local script doesn't have any typos, how can you tell thats the reason?